# Reading individual bits from Memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

To convert a number from base 10 to base 2, I thought of directly reading bits from memory instead of performing bitshift (`>>`).

Consider the program:

```
int n = 14;
bool* pointer = (bool*)&n;
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    cout << *(p + i);
```

The program is not giving the correct output.

The program below works:

```
int n = 14;
bool *p = (bool*)&n;
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
    cout << *p;
    n = n >> 1;
}
```

Bitshifting wastes unnecessary time. Also please point out the error in the first code snippet.

Comment: "Bitshifting wastes unnecessary time." - What is your problem? Performance? How did you profile or benchmark? What did you expect? What is the Assembler code? Why do you expect an `int` to have 32 bits? Why a `bool` with 32 bits? What does your implementation say about right-shifting a signed integer?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that `sizeof bool == 32 / 8` - That's wrong.

Comment: If you think bitshifting is a waste of time, you've probably never read your processor's manual.

Comment: @Olaf read again - he's *not* working with an `int` - even worse

Comment: A `bool` is not a bit. There is no way to address single bits.

Comment: How does the second one work: http://ideone.com/gtFqbR . Does it give the correct output?

Comment: I think what you MIGHT be looking for here is the bitwise and operator (&)

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad It is giving the correct output on my machine (clang compiler). The output you received seems weird as *p should be a bit which can only be 1 or 0.

Comment: If you want to read bits from memory, you can loop and check if the `i`th bit is `1` or `0` as `n & (1 << i)`

Comment: @tofro: IIRC C++ behavhes here like C and coerces the 'bool' to `int` for the shift. But yes, the code is really bad. It's not really clear what OP intendended.

Comment: `n` is not base 10, but base 2 on a binary digital computer. Do you have a decimal digital computer? Very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

If you really are worried that shifting is too expensive (which is only really true on some older CPUs, like the 68008, for example), you can work with constant bit masks like so:

```
const unsigned int table [] = {0x00000001, 0x00000002, 0x00000004, 0x00000008,
                               0x00000010, 0x00000020, 0x00000040, 0x00000080,
                               // ...rinse and repeat until bit 31....
                              };

int isSet (unsigned int value, int bitNo) {
   return ((value & table [bitNo]) != 0);
}
```

What you have shown above is not going to work for a gazillion of reasons, some are in the comments you have received.